# How to do a match statement with resource type?

Tags: smartcontracts, scrypto, radix-dlt

I want to find out if a resource passed as a bucket to my method is a Fungible or non fungible resource (the action is different in each case)

I tried this:

```
let resource_man = bucket.resource_manager();
match resource_man.resource_type() {
  ResourceType::NonmFungible => {//do something here}
  ResourceType::Fungible => {//do another here}
}
```

But I get this error:
`error[E0533]: expected unit struct, unit variant or constant, found struct variant 'ResourceType::NonFungible'`

How to work around this and getthe flow control I want?

Comment: tried also 
```let x = bucket.resource_manager().resource_type();
match ResourceType {
  x if x == ResourceType::NonFungible => ()
  x if x == ResourceType::Fungible => () }```

as per sugestion on ewrror explanation:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/error_codes/E0533.html

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```rust
let resource_man = bucket.resource_manager();
match resource_man.resource_type() {
   ResourceType::NonFungible { .. } => {//do something here},
   ResourceType::Fungible { .. } => {//do another here}
};
```

The types have their own fields which you have to match on: https://radixdlt.github.io/radixdlt-scrypto/scrypto/blueprints/resource/enum.ResourceType.html. The `..` ignores these fields (I'm assuming you don't care about them).

Edit: to elaborate a bit more.. you could match on divisibility, for example:

```rust
let resource_man = bucket.resource_manager();
match resource_man.resource_type() {
   ResourceType::NonFungible { .. } => {//do something here},
   ResourceType::Fungible{ divisibility: 18 } => { // do something with divisibility 18 fungibles here},
   ResourceType::Fungible{ divisibility: 17 } => { // do something with divisibility 17 fungibles here},
   ResourceType::Fungible{ .. } => { // do something for the rest }
};
```